# A problem with pgfcalendar and fpu

Tags: pgfmath, calendar, fpu

I'm trying to define a macro that will determine two dates (in weeks of 7 days), calculated from a given date (defined by `\setmovedate` below. For brevity the code below uses only `#2` from `\movetasks`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[papersize={5.5in,8.5in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}

\newcounter{testit}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\setmovedate}{m}{%
    \pgfcalendardatetojulian{#1}{\@tempcnta}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\movetasks}{mm}{%
    %% Commenting-out the \pgfkeys lines gives 'dimension too large' error
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}% Turn on the fp engine
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\fromdate}{add(\the\@tempcnta,-7*#2)}\fromdate\ trailing 0's from fpu\\
    \pgfcalendarjuliantodate{\fromdate}{\moveyear}{\movemonth}{\moveday} Ejects 0's from fpu\\
    \moveyear-\movemonth-\moveday\ is correct
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setmovedate{2019-10-15}

\movetasks{2}{3}

\end{document}
```

[image: fpu and pgfcalendar]

I understand the trailing 0's in `\fromdate` (the output from `fpu`) but I'm puzzled by the fact that they are discarded by `\pgfcalendarjuliantodate` and subsequently printed. Clearly, a simple integer is required, but my attempts to do this have, thus far, proved futile. I'm probably missing something very basic which is annoying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert the result to an integer (perhaps you need to round first, to get the nearest integer):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[papersize={5.5in,8.5in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}

\newcounter{testit}

\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand{\setmovedate}{m}{%
    \pgfcalendardatetojulian{#1}{\@tempcnta}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\movetasks}{mm}{%
    %% Commenting-out the \pgfkeys lines gives 'dimension too large' error
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu/output format=float}% Turn on the fp engine
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\fromdate}{int(add(\the\@tempcnta,-7*#2))}%
    \pgfmathfloattoint{\fromdate}%<---
    \pgfcalendarjuliantodate{\pgfmathresult}{\moveyear}{\movemonth}{\moveday}%
    \moveyear-\movemonth-\moveday\ is correct
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setmovedate{2019-10-15}

\movetasks{2}{3}

\end{document}
```